# How to store Excel, CSV file in temporary storage like cookies, session in .Net core mvc c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, model-view-controller, local-storage

I store IFormfile in static class and convert it into memory stream but it shows this error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'FileBufferingReadStream'.'

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())            
{
   IFormFile tempFile = ExcelDataValidation.DLExcelFile; 
   tempFile.CopyTo(stream); //Error shows here
}
```

Comment: _"I store IFormfile in `static` class"_ - **you can't do that**: an `IFormFile`'s lifespan is its parent `HttpContext`: you _must_ consume (i.e. read and process) an `IFormFile` within its request/response lifespan.